# Split string when single comma occurs and not split when more than one comma occurs in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

--case#1

```
select '1,2,,2,3,4,,,4,5, , ,, , ,, , ,,,,,,5,6' from dual;
```

--case#2

```
select q'[1aaaaaa, bbb,  bbbb (cccc,,ccccc) 20,,,20-09-30 11:11:11 (dddddddd): below eeeeeee is ddddd of teh dddd. ajhvajshbfjasbhfjkabsdfkjabsfkljbaaksjfka . 569716476@@asdasa asdasdi (asfasfasf) 2020-09-30 22:22:27 (sdfsdfal): As per sdfsdfsdfg sdfm: sds the below is a sdfsdf@@@@3**** sd sd sdd sdffve sdffin with sdf ��� the below is correct. the "sdfd" sds tsd sdfe fsI as sdfL. hsdfe we do not sdffte fsw dsddDs123**** just new sdfsdng ssdfsds.@@sdfsda sdfsdni (sdffdsdUP) 2020-09-23 22:31:54 (sdffsdal): sdil zxct cx Gzxcz zxcc: zxcc/zxI-Jcxz- cx zxccx***zxccc rzxcczxc***. 569zxc476@@zxccxi zxcxzze (zxcczxzxc) 2020-02-28 22:21:26, (zxtezxcxz) 03/28-As per zxcc, ,, ,,, , ,,,,,, ,zxzxx by cx cxcx zxzz is zxcxzz zxcxz zxcc. zxc zx]'
from dual;
```

--case#3

```
Please just copy paste the string present in Case#2 several times so that the overall length increase 4000 characters and try you solution.
```

This string should split whenever single comma comes and should not split for multi occurrence of comma like double/triple or so on.

Also, if anyone can just replace the above multiple commas with some string like 12345 then it will work for me. Do not replace single comma

Note the above string is coming from a CLOB column so need an efficient query which should take less cpu.

```
o/p:
1
2,,2
3
4,,,4
5, , ,, , ,, , ,,,,,,5     -- NOTE: this has multiple commas with space
6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Oracle 11gR2, you can use:

```sql
WITH strings (value, end_pos, term) AS (
  SELECT value,
         REGEXP_INSTR(value, '((\d+(, *){2,})*\d+)(,|$)', 1, 1, 1),
         REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, '((\d+(, *){2,})*\d+)(,|$)', 1, 1, NULL, 1)
  FROM   table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT value,
         REGEXP_INSTR(value, '((\d+(, *){2,})*\d+)(,|$)', end_pos, 1, 1),
         REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, '((\d+(, *){2,})*\d+)(,|$)', end_pos, 1, NULL, 1)
  FROM   strings
  WHERE  end_pos > 0
)
SELECT term
FROM   strings
WHERE  end_pos > 0;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( value ) AS
select '1,2,,2,3,4,,,4,5, , ,, , ,, , ,,,,,,5,6' from dual;
```

Outputs:

> | TERM |
> | --- |
> | 1 |
> | 2,,2 |
> | 3 |
> | 4,,,4 |
> | 5, , ,, , ,, , ,,,,,,5 |
> | 6 |

---

An alternative that may work in earlier versions is:

```sql
SELECT RTRIM(
         REGEXP_SUBSTR(
           t.value,
           '((\d+(, *){2,})*\d+)(,|$)',
           1,
           l.COLUMN_VALUE
         ),
         ','
       ) AS term
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS JOIN
       TABLE(
         CAST(
           MULTISET(
             SELECT LEVEL
             FROM   DUAL
             CONNECT BY
                    REGEXP_INSTR(
                      t.value,
                      '((\d+(, *){2,})*\d+)(,|$)',
                      1,
                      LEVEL
                    ) > 0
           )
           AS SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST
         )
       ) l
```

*sqlfiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9a8a2/14)*

Comment: Please modify the query so that it can work for string too. For eg - select 'a,b,,b,c,d,,,d,e, , ,, , ,, , ,,,,,,e,f' from dual;  The actual string is a long text.

Comment: @swet Just replace each instance of `\d` with `[0-9a-zA-Z]` if you want alpha-numeric strings. Also, if you have different data then you should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68573163/edit) your question to include a representative sample of the data because, if you don't then people will answer the question you actually asked rather than the question in your head that we know nothing about.

Comment: the query is not behaving correctly with long string. Can you please try Case#2 and #3 which are just added to the question, thanks.

Comment: @swet That is, again, because you did not define the scope of the problem initially and only gave a minimal dataset that was not actually representative of your problem so we can only answer the question you asked based on the incorrect data you give us. Use `[^,]` instead of `\d`. [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4b9d74/1)